# Largest and smallest number in an array

Tags: c#

This works perfectly...but when I use `foreach` instead of `for` this doesn't works. I can't understand `for` and `foreach` are same.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = new int[10];
            Console.WriteLine("enter the array elements to b sorted");
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            int smallest = array[0];
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)

            {
                if(array[i]<smallest)
                {
                    smallest=array[i];

                }
            }
            int largest = array[9];
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {

                if (array[i] > largest)
                {
                    largest = array[i];

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("the smallest no is {0}", smallest);
            Console.WriteLine("the largest no is {0}", largest);
            Console.Read();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the foreach code that you tried an didn't work. you're probably doing something wrong

Comment: I'm curious why you say `int largest = array[9];`. Why not taking first element by default?

Answer (score 38):

Why are you not using this?

```
int[] array = { 12, 56, 89, 65, 61, 36, 45, 23 };
int max = array.Max();
int min = array.Min();
```

Comment: Smells like homework. His teacher probably didn't went there yet.

Comment: If it is homework, he is likely to be trying to implement the method himself rather than using a built in one (and perhaps finding the loop invariants).

Comment: +1 if you tell me where I can find Max() :p , it doesn't seem to be in System.Array, I am using a long[]

Comment: `Max` and `Min` are LINQ extension methods on `System.IEnumerable`, which Array implements. See [IEnumerable.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340489).

Comment: You can also find Math.Min(decimal, decimal) in the system namespace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45188f55.aspx

Answer (score 11):

If you need to use foreach (for some reason) and don't want to use bult-in functions, here is a code snippet:

```
int minint = array[0];
int maxint = array[0];
foreach (int value in array) {
  if (value < minint) minint = value;
  if (value > maxint) maxint = value;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
   static void PrintSmallestLargest(int[] arr)
    {
        if (arr.Length > 0)
        {
            int small = arr[0];
            int large = arr[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (large < arr[i])
                {
                    int tmp = large;
                    large = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = large;
                }
                if (small > arr[i])
                {
                    int tmp = small;
                    small = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = small;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Smallest is {0}", small);
            Console.WriteLine("Largest is {0}", large);
        }
    }
```

This way you can have smallest and largest number in a single loop.

Comment: There is no requirement for temporary variables and then again assigning it to the array.

Answer (score 3):

You (normally) cannot modify the collection you are iterating over when using foreach.

Although for and foreach seem to be similar from a developer perspective they are quite different from an implementation perspective.

`Foreach` uses an `Iterator` to access the individual objects while `for` doesn't know (or care) about the underlying object sequence.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public int MinimumValue { get; private set; }
    public int MaxmimumValue { get; private set; }

    public void num()
    {
        int[] array = { 12, 56, 89, 65, 61, 36, 45, 23 };
        MaxmimumValue = array[0];
        MinimumValue = array[0];

        foreach (int num in array)

        {

            if (num > MaxmimumValue) MaxmimumValue = num;
            if (num < MinimumValue) MinimumValue = num;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(MinimumValue);
        Console.WriteLine(MaxmimumValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

namespace greatest
{

    class Greatest
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {   
            //get the number of elements
            Console.WriteLine("enter the number of elements");
            int i;
            i=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] abc = new int[i];         
            //accept the elements
            for(int size=-1; size<i; size++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter the elements");
                abc[size]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            //Greatest
            int max=abc.Max();
            int min=abc.Min();
            Console.WriteLine("the m", max);
            Console.WriteLine("the mi", min);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all code lines need to be indented (at least) 4 spaces for the formatter to work. Also they need to be separated from surrounding text (if any) by a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

Generic extension method (Gets `Min` and `Max` in one iteration):

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static (T Min, T Max) MinMax<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        T min = source.FirstOrDefault();
        T max = source.FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            if (item.CompareTo(min) == -1)
            {
                min = item;
            }
            if (item.CompareTo(max) == 1)
            {
                max = item;
            }
        }

        return (Min: min, Max: max);
    }

}
```

> This code used C# 7  Tuple

Answer (score 0):

```
Int[] number ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
Int? Result = null;
 foreach(Int i in number)

    {
       If(!Result.HasValue || i< Result)

        { 

            Result =i;
         }
     }

     Console.WriteLine(Result);
   }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the complete programme give Below**`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace oops3
{  
    public class Demo
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the size of the array");
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] arr = new int[x];
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the elements of the array");
            for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
            {
                arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            int smallest = arr[0];
            int Largest = arr[0];
            for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
            {
                if(smallest>arr[i])
                {
                    smallest = arr[i];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                if (Largest< arr[i])
                {
                    Largest = arr[i];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The greater No in the array:" + Largest);
            Console.WriteLine("The smallest No in the array:" + smallest);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Array_Small_and_lagest {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int[] array = new int[10];
            Console.WriteLine("enter the array elements to b sorted");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            int smallest = array[0];
            foreach (int i in array) {
                if (i < smallest) {
                    smallest = i;    
                }
            }
            int largest = array[9];
            foreach (int i in array) {    
                if (i > largest) {
                    largest = i;    
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("the smallest no is {0}", smallest);
            Console.WriteLine("the largest no is {0}", largest);
            Console.Read();        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a long time. Maybe like this:

```
    public int smallestValue(int[] values)
    {
        int smallest = int.MaxValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            smallest = (values[i] < smallest ? values[i] : smallest);
        }

        return smallest;
    }


    public static int largestvalue(int[] values)
    {
        int largest = int.MinValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            largest = (values[i] > largest ? values[i] : largest);
        }

        return largest;
    }
```