# How to returns the maximum number found in the array in c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, max

I am new to C# language. After googling I am not able to find appropriate answer please give me some solution to do this.

"I want to write a method that receives as parameter an array of integers and returns the maximum number found in the array in c#"

Comment: If you had actually googled that sentence you've quoted you would've seen that the topmost entry is this: [StackOverflow: Largest and smallest number in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906725/largest-and-smallest-number-in-an-array), which shows exactly what you should do.

Comment: Consider to familiarize yourself with LINQ. This contains a lot of useful functions that work with every kind of sequence, or to be more precise: every object where you can say "Give me your first element"  and "Give me your next element". There are functions to find the Min and the Max of a sequence. Learn LINQ at http://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx

Comment: i want to know what is the difference between Max and Largest in array. I am bit confused

Answer (score 2):

Try IEnumerable.Max().

```
//remember to add "System.Linq" to your usings
int maxVal = yourArray.Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LINQ to collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) method [Max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534331(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public int GetMax(IReadOnlyCollection<int> source)
{
    return source.Max(x => x);
}
```

[LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) is a powerful .net part to manipulating (queering, filtering, grouping, etc.) collections and objects that have providers to data-sources like databases and can be used in many scenarios.