# How do display the largest integer in an array using the Find method in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I made a small array of integers from 1 to 5, and I want to output the largest integer. I have seen many examples, but none using the Find method.
This is how my code looks so far. I don't know how to finish it.

```
static void Main()
        {
            int[] arr =  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

            int result = Array.Find(arr.Max);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

What should it look like?

Comment: [`Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Max_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Int32__) returns an `int` representing the maximum value. `Array.Find` takes an array as its first element, and a predicate (a condition that returns true/false) as its second argument.

Comment: `arr.Max();` would probably do the trick

Comment: Why do you need to use `Array.Find`? `Enumerable.Max` is intended for this exact purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to returns the maximum number found in the array in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396140/how-to-returns-the-maximum-number-found-in-the-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I know the above is not a direct duplicate, but you should really be using `Enumerable.Max`. Using `Find()` + `Max()` is really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

If your homework assignment insists that you use Array.Find() then try:

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    int result = Array.Find(arr, i => i == arr.Max());

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

but it is entirely redundant.

```
int result = arr.Max();
```

is more efficient and more legible.

Answer (score 0):

So I think what you're attempting to use Find for, is not its intention.

Find is to return a result when it matches a given predicate.  So as an example it would work like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] arr =  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // this is just a lambda to check if each number given to it is even, and if so returns true.
    int result = Array.Find(arr, p => p % 2 == 0);

    // "2" gets output as its the first even number it found.
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

check out more at the developer docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.find?view=netcore-3.1