# Finding minimum value from list

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, min

How would i build an algorithm here in the most efficient way possible to find minimum value from list? I know the list hasnt done in the best way but, any ideas how to do ?
I have tried few ways but dont seem to get it work efficiently..

Thanks.

```
class MainClass
{

    public class List
    {

        public int maxSize = 50;
        public int MaxSize
        {
            get
            {
                return maxSize;
            }
            set
            {
                maxSize = value;
            }
        }


        public int firstEmpty = 0;
        public int FirstEmpty
        {
            get
            {
                return firstEmpty;
            }
            set
            {
                firstEmpty = value;
            }
        }

        public int[] data;


        public List()
        {
            data = new int[maxSize];
        }


        public int returnValueAtIndex(int i)
        {
            return data[i];
        }


        public void setValueAtIndex(int v, int i)
        {
            data[i] = v;
        }

    }



    public static int FIRST(List L)
    {
        if (END(L) > 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public static int END(List L)
    {
        return L.FirstEmpty;
    }

    public static int NEXT(int p, List L)
    {
        if (p >= 0 && p < L.MaxSize && p < END(L))
            return p+1;
        else
            return - 1;
    }

    public static int PREVIOUS(int p, List L)
    {
        if (p >= 0 && p < L.MaxSize && p <= END(L))
            return p-1;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public static int LOCATE (int x, List L)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i<END(L) && RETRIEVE(i, L) != x)
        {
            i++;
        }
        if (i != END(L))
            return i;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public static int RETRIEVE(int p, List L)
    {
        if (p >= 0 && p < END(L))
            return L.returnValueAtIndex(p);
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public static void INSERT(int x, int p, List L)
    {
        if (p >= 0 && p < L.MaxSize && p <= END(L))
        {
            if (p == END(L))
            {
                L.setValueAtIndex(x, p);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = END(L); i > p; i--)
                {
                    L.setValueAtIndex(L.returnValueAtIndex(i - 1), i);
                    L.setValueAtIndex(x, p);
                }
            }
            L.FirstEmpty = END(L) + 1;
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Alkiota ei voitu lisätä");
    }

    public void DELETE(int p, List L)
    {
        if (p >= 0 && p < END(L))
        {
            for (int i = p; i < p - 1; i++)
            {
                L.setValueAtIndex(L.returnValueAtIndex(i + 1), i);
            }
            L.FirstEmpty = END(L) - 1;
        }

    }
    public void MAKENULL(List L)
    {
        L.FirstEmpty = 0;
    }

    public static void PRINT(List L)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Listan sisältö:");
        for (int i = 0; i < END(L); i++)
        {
            Console.Write(L.returnValueAtIndex(i) + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }





    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List testilista = new List();
        INSERT(2, END(testilista), testilista);
        INSERT(7, END(testilista), testilista);
        INSERT(9, END(testilista), testilista);
        INSERT(12, END(testilista), testilista);
        INSERT(9, END(testilista), testilista);
        INSERT(38, END(testilista), testilista);


        Console.WriteLine("testilista");
        PRINT(testilista);



        Console.ReadLine();


    }
}
```

}

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Specifically what are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Creating most efficient algorithm possible on this framework to find minimum value for the list

Comment: Please notice, that List and Array are two different types of storing data, you call your class List but in reality you are using an Array inside of that class.

Comment: thats why im having trouble

Comment: i meant that to get algorithm work with array that has already inserted values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Largest and smallest number in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906725/largest-and-smallest-number-in-an-array)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do that in C# is with LinQ:

```
var minValue = data.Min();
```

if you want the highest value:

```
var maxValue = data.Max();
```

Comment: I just tried it in a C# forms application before posting it here and i got the min-value from my Array without casting it in a list.

Comment: You are totally right, my mistake, I was mis-remembering which classes could use `Min()`, I'll remove my comment since it is inaccurate

Answer (score 2):

Note: Answer is not specific to C#

Given an unordered list of numbers, the fastest way to find the smallest number in the list is to look at every element in the list.

```
var unorderedList = [5,4,3,2,6,7,-23,8,-64,2,0,6];

function findSmallest(anArray){
    var lowest = anArray[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < anArray.length; i++){
        var num = anArray[i];
        if(num < lowest){
            lowest = num;
        }
    }

    return lowest;
}

var smallest = findSmallest(unorderedList);

console.log(smallest); //prints -64
```

You can run the code [here](https://repl.it/BluP/1)

hit the run button

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best option. For me there is two ways.

Sort your list by this code.

```
int valueMin = L.returnValueAtIndex(0);

for (int i = 0; i < END(L); i++)
{
   //if the value of i is smaller than the value
   if (valueMin < L.returnValueAtIndex(i))
   {
       //i become the min Value
       valueMin = L.returnValueAtIndex(i);
   } 
}

Console.WriteLine(valueMin);
Console.Read();
```

Or in C# you can use Array.Sort

```
Array.Sort(L);
Console.WriteLine(L.returnValueAtIndex(0));
Console.Read();
```

I hope this will help you !

Comment: Sorting the array is slower than just searching every value in the array once, and since he is looking for "the most efficient way possible", this is worse than Gabs00's answer

Comment: I said "I don't think this is the best option", sorry if i'm a rookie.. This is better ? int[] list = { 6, 9, 8, 2 };
            int minValue = list.Min();

Comment: My mistake, I thought you meant that what the other people were doing was not the best option. `list.Min()` would be a better option, but that is exactly what Marcel B already suggested

Comment: Yes, big up to him. I was looking for this answer on my IDE after your comment. He was too fast for me. Have a nice day!