# Method that compares two arrays, finds largest number and prints array with the largest number

Tags: c#, arrays

If i have two arrays of type double like

```
double [] a1 = { 15, 7, 8 };
double [] a2 = { 10, 5 };
```

And i want to create a method which takes these as arguments, compares them and prints the full array which houses the largest number? Like this:

```
double[] result = HasLargestElement(a1,a2);
foreach (double x in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

I'am trying to learn how to do this in a more simple manner which im then gonna implement into my project, but i have no idea how this should be done.. I am a real beginner with c# so take that in mind, not much experience at all just started out.

**Update:**

Code looks now like this:

```
class Largest
{
    double[] a1 = { 15, 7, 8 };
    double[] a2 = { 10, 5, 14, 3 };


    static void Main(string[] args) {
    public double[] LargestElement(double[] a1, double[] a2)
    {
        var v1 = a1.Max();
        var v2 = a2.Max();

        if (v1 > v2)
            return v1;
        return v2;
    }

    public double HasLargestElement(double[] a1, double[] a2)
    {
        return a1.Max() > a2.Max() ? a1 : a2;
    }
}
```

But I receive a compiler error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double[]' to 'double'

Anyone see an issue? As said i am started 2 days ago with this. If someone could edit my code it would be amazing, i just want to see how this works properly

Comment: how would you do it manually?

Comment: Forget code, write an algorithm. Once you're satisfied, *then* write the code.

Comment: When you say houses the largest number, do you mean the collection which has the single largest double in it? Or the collection with the most number of elements?

Comment: I mean the largest number within the collection

Comment: `a1.Max() > a2.Max() ? a1 : a2;`

Comment: @Bidou that is gorgeous.

Comment: @AndersOnander, in the current code you just shared, you need to change `public double HasLargestElement` to `public double[] HasLargestElement`.

Comment: @adv12 It still does not work

Comment: What does "does not work" mean exactly? Compiler error, what? Runtime exception, what?

Comment: @abatishchev I get the same error, cannot implicitly convert type...

Comment: @abatishchev You see any errors in the code above?

Comment: There are plenty of errors in the code above, you have two methods inside of your main method, you don't have enough closing braces. HasLargestElement returns a double when it should return double[]. It seems like you are very new to programming, you should do some tutorials. Start with something like Hello World and understanding definitions and syntax.

Comment: @FrumRoll Could you fix it please? I just want to learn and see how this would work..

Comment: v1 and v2 are a single number. not an array of numbers. You need to be returning a1 and a2. Then you need to add a curly brace to the bottom of the file. Then move your code outside of the main method. Alternatively you can copy/paste my answer directly in main method. Just add the missing curly brace.

Comment: @AndersOnander: I don't understand how `public double[] HasLargestElement` can still return the same compiler error...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Linq` extension methods to accomplish this.

```
using System.Linq;

var result = a1.Max() > a2.Max() ? a1 : a2;
foreach (var x in result)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it for you

```
double [] a1 = {15, 7, 8};
double [] a2 = {10, 5};
var max = a1.Max() > a2.Max()?a1:a2;
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, max));
```

And since you wanted someone to fix your code so you can see how it works here you go:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Largest
    {
        private static double[] a1 = {15, 7, 8};
        private static double[] a2 = {10, 5, 14, 3};

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var arrayWithlargestElement = HasLargestElement(a1,a2);
            Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, arrayWithlargestElement));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static double[] HasLargestElement(double[] a1, double[] a2)
        {
            return a1.Max() > a2.Max() ? a1 : a2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like string.Join, but given OP's example Environment.NewLine seems like a better separator than ","?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the following in your 'HasLargestElement' array.

```
if (a1.Max() > a2.Max()){
     return a1;
}
else return a2;
```

There is more information under this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906725/largest-and-smallest-number-in-an-array)

Comment: @abatishchev How come? It returns the correct array as Anders wanted. I will say some of the other methods are neater though.

Comment: And the difference with `return a1.Max() > a2.Max() ? a1 : a2;` given above first times is..?

Comment: That wasnt there when I submitted my answer, but that is a much tidier solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public double LargestElement(double[] a1, double[] a2)
{
    var v1 = a1.Max();
    var v2 = a2.Max();

    if(v1>v2)
       return v1;
    return v2;
}

public double[] HasLargestElement(double[] a1, double[] a2)
{
    return a1.Max() > a2.Max() ? a1 : a2;
}
```

Comment: I want to return the full array which houses the largest element

Comment: @AndersOnander added func for that as well

Comment: Do you see where is issue could be?

Comment: This won't compile, would it?

Comment: @abatishchev not familiar with C# syntax but I think the second method should return a double array - `double[]`. There is a pending edit about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Largest
{
    double[] a1;
    double[] a2;

    public Largest()
    {
    }

    public void compareArray()
    {

        if (a1.Max() > a2.Max())
        {
            foreach (var x in a1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var x in a2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Largest compare = new Largest();
        compare.a1 = new double[5] { 14, 7, 3, 7, 1 };
        compare.a2 = new double[5] { 13, 24, 3, 6, 11};
        compare.compareArray();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Almost completly new code, got it working.